# как при наведении на ссылку меню показать блок не принадлежащий родительскому?

Tags: css

есть меню

```html
<li><a class="down_menu" href="javascript:void(0)">Services</a><li>

<div class="dropdownmenu">
   <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Нужно при наведении на down_menu показался блок dropdownmenu

но чтобы можно было выбирать эти меню т.е чтобы блок не закрывался когда уберу курсор с down_menu а когда убрать курсор с выпадающего меню dropdownmenu тогда чтобы закрывалось.

СПАСИБО

Comment: да не за что, с чего начнём?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.dropdownmenu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  right: -10%;
}

.down_menu {
  position: relative;
}

.down_menu:hover .dropdownmenu,
.dropdownmenu:hover {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<li>
  <a class="down_menu">
            Services
            <div class="dropdownmenu">
                <ul>
                    <li>1</li>
                    <li>2</li>
                    <li>3</li>
                    <li>4</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </a>
  <li>
```

*Как добавить CSS (пример): если таблица стилей ещё не подключена, создадим файл styles.css, напишем туда код что я написал выше, и в вашем HTML перед тэгом < body > добавим:*

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
```